# Decrease default checkbox size in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am developing a blood bank in django, and when updating the details of receiver in webpage,

I have a checkbox called 'show details in receiver list' when rendering that checkbox from `{{form.showDetails}}` the size of the checkbox is huge and I cannot resize the size of that checkbox.
The image of the checkbox is here:
[image]

If you have any idea to resize that box please share it. It would help me a lot. I have tried to decrease the size of that division but it did not help.
And the code when rendering the checkbox data from the database is below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="inputAllergies" class="form-label">Show details in receiver list:</label>
        <div class="form-input" style="background-color:red; height: 20px;">
          {{ form.showDetails}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add a <style> tag and resize the checkbox in it using the checkbox ID or type?

Comment: i will try that